# Python: Realizar multiples plots (Dudas)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Soy nuevo en Python y necesito hacer una función que recorra todas las columnas del dataframe y plotee en un subplot dichas columnas. He creado una función para esto mismo, pero plotea repetidamente las columnas por cada iteración y arroja un ValueError. Adjunto el código y su output.

```
def view_outliers(df):
 nrows = 4
 ncol = 2 
 fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows,ncol, figsize=(10,8))
  for column in df:
    if df[column].dtype != np.object_: #Filtrado de objects y categories
        
        for r in range(nrows):
            for c in range(ncol):
                df[column].plot(kind='box', ax=axs[r,c])

view_outliers(df3)
```

Arroja el siguiente output:

```
Output: ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (2), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (1).
```

El resultado esperado es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de por qué puede ser? ¡Muchas gracias comunidad!

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto para que las respuestas puedan aplicarse más fácilmente a lo que estás haciendo, de otra forma la respuesta sería muy genérica y tendrías que adaptarla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias a los que respondieron. Ya lo he resuelto con el siguiente algoritmo:

```
def quick_outliers(df):
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,2, figsize=(20,20))
for i, column in zip(df.index, df): 
    if df[column].dtype != np.object_: 
        axes = ax.ravel() 
        df[column].plot(kind='box', ax=axes[i])
            
quick_outliers(df3)
```